# Generate list of dates and store in database

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I am reasking a question I had asked earlier today.  Is it possible to generate a list of dates, being provided only with the first and last ones, and then storing the resulting list in a database table, with each date taking a new row:

Example 
Row 1: 2015-08-10
Row 2: 2015-08-11
Row 3: 2015-08-12
Row ..: ..
Row 10: 2015-08-20

```
<?php

    $apartment = (isset($_POST['apartment']) ? $_POST['apartment'] : null);
    $name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null);
    $surname = (isset($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : null);
    $email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);
    $address = (isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null);
    $mobile = (isset($_POST['mobile']) ? $_POST['mobile'] : null);
    $pax = (isset($_POST['pax']) ? $_POST['pax'] : null);
    $address = (isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null);
    $remarks = (isset($_POST['remarks']) ? $_POST['remarks'] : null);
    $day_from = (isset($_POST['day_from']) ? $_POST['day_from'] : null);
    $month_from = (isset($_POST['month_from']) ? $_POST['month_from'] : null);
    $year_from = (isset($_POST['year_from']) ? $_POST['year_from'] : null);
    $booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from;
    $day_to = (isset($_POST['day_to']) ? $_POST['day_to'] : null);
    $month_to = (isset($_POST['month_to']) ? $_POST['month_to'] : null);
    $year_to = (isset($_POST['year_to']) ? $_POST['year_to'] : null);
    $booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
    $no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) - strtotime($booking_from));     
    $days = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));

 // current method of creatign the list of dates. 
    function daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
  $dates = array();
  $first = strtotime($booking_from);
  $last = strtotime($booking_to);

  while ($first <= $last) {
    $dates[] = date($output_format, $first);
    $first = strtotime($step, $first);
  }

  return $dates;
}

$dates = daterange($booking_from, $booking_to);

print_r($dates);

 include 'connect.php';

 if (!$conn->autocommit(FALSE)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO client_details (clientID, name, email, address, mobile) VALUES ('', '$name $surname', '$email', '$address', '$mobile')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }


 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO bookings (bookingID, apartmentID, clientID, date_from, date_to, nights, pax, remarks) VALUES ('', '$apartment', LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$booking_from', '$booking_to', '$days', '$pax', '$remarks')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

// table in which the dates are to be inserted 
 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO room_nights (bookingID, apartmentID, date_from, date_to) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$apartment', '$dates[0]', '". $dates[count($dates) - 1] ."')")) {
      printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }


 if (!$conn->commit()) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
 $conn->close();

 ?>
```

> Current table result 
>   date_from     date_to     bookingID   apartmentID     
>   2015-08-10     2015-08-13  1   1
>   2015-08-17     2015-08-20  2   1
>
> Desired result 
>   date bookingID apartmentID
>   2015-08-10 1 1
>   2015-08-11 1 1
>   2015-08-12 1 1

Comment: Don't re-ask questions especially on the same day.

Comment: I apologise for that but I was kinda getting desperate. :/

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `DateTime` suite of classes makes this easier:

```
function daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
  $dates = array();
  $first = new DateTime($booking_from);
  $last  = (new DateTime($booking_to))->modify('+' . $step);
  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($step);
  $period = new DatePeriod($first, $interval, $last);

  foreach ($period as $date) {
    $dates[] = $date->format($output_format);
  }

  return $dates;
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/415006)

This creates two `DateTime()` objects, one for the starting date, one for the ending date. It also creates a `DateInterval()` object which represents the steps between dates and a `DatePeriod()` objects stores them all. Then we loop through the `DatePeriod()` object and get our formatted date.

Comment: How would I save the result in the database?

Comment: That's an entirely different issue. Just loop through the dates array and insert each value.

Comment: aaa ok thanks - will try to figure it out.

Comment: Have sort of figured it out, however for some reason I'm getting a bunch of 0000-00-00 instead of the actual dates in the database.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the question -

```
<?php


    $day_from = (isset($_POST['day_from']) ? $_POST['day_from'] : null);
    $month_from = (isset($_POST['month_from']) ? $_POST['month_from'] : null);
    $year_from = (isset($_POST['year_from']) ? $_POST['year_from'] : null);
    $booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from;
    $day_to = (isset($_POST['day_to']) ? $_POST['day_to'] : null);
    $month_to = (isset($_POST['month_to']) ? $_POST['month_to'] : null);
    $year_to = (isset($_POST['year_to']) ? $_POST['year_to'] : null);
    $booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
    $no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) - strtotime($booking_from));     
    $days = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));

function daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
  $dates = array();
  $first = new DateTime($booking_from);
  $last = new DateTime($booking_to);
  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($step);
  $period = new DatePeriod($first, $interval, $last);

  foreach ($period as $date) {
      $dates[] = $date->format($output_format);
  }

  return $dates;
}

$dates = daterange($booking_from, $booking_to);

print_r($dates);

 include 'connect.php';

 if (!$conn->autocommit(FALSE)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }


 foreach ($dates as $date) {
 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO room_nights (bookingID, apartmentID, dates) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$apartment', '$date')")) {
      printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
 }

 if (!$conn->commit()) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
 $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Answer it on your original question so that this one can be deleted without losing your answer